# Is there a list of the node names for the node_tree.nodes.new() function in blender 2.82?

Tags: python, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to add nodes to a material using bpy in blender 2.8, but I cannot find a list of names to refer to them in the new() function
IE:
`mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ColorRamp')`
doesn't work, because it is actually `mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeValToRGB')`
and I need a list of all the names of these, so if anyone knows where to find them I'd love to know, as I cannot find it in the documentation

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNode.html#module-bpy.types.ShaderNode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will give a list of all names. Note that which ones you can add depends on the type of node tree eg. you can't add "CompositorNodeXXX" nodes to a shader node tree.

```py
[
  name
  for name in dir(bpy.types)
  if issubclass(getattr(bpy.types, name), bpy.types.Node)
  if getattr(bpy.types, name).is_registered_node_type()  # exclude base classes like Node
]
```

An easier way to find them, IMO, is if you have "Python Tooltips" turned on in prefs, you can hover over the items in the "Add" menu to see the name to use.

[image: Tooltip showing "ColorRamp" corresponds to "ShaderNodeValToRGB"]

Comment: Could look instead  at subclass of `bpy.types.ShaderNode` for shader nodes... or name starts with "ShaderNode"

Answer (score 1):

Updated script:

```
import bpy
import inspect

for name in dir(bpy.types):
    if inspect.isclass(getattr(bpy.types, name)):
        if issubclass(getattr(bpy.types, name), bpy.types.Node):
            if getattr(bpy.types, name).is_registered_node_type():  # exclude base classes
                print(name)
```